# How to render OpenStreetMaps?

Tags: dictionary, openstreetmap

Did you know a way to render the .osm format given by OpenStreetMap in Php, JavaScript, ActionScript or other web plataform? What do you recomend to implement it? Where can i find good examples in the plataform you suggest? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the information here on several rendering softwares http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Rendering

Also look at Cartagen which is an MIT Media lab project that renders OSM and other data in a HTML5 Canvas element dynamically on the client-side. http://www.cartagen.org/